# Dialog fadeOut leaves bounding box

Tags: javascript, jquery

I create my JQuery Dialog like this

```
  $(thisDialog).dialog({
                open: function (event, ui) {
                    $(this).parent().children('.ui-dialog-titlebar').hide(); //hide titlebar.
                },
                position: [leftPos, topPos]
            });
```

I tried to fade it out like this, and I can't re-open it and a bounding box remains.

```
setTimeout((function () { $(thisDialog).fadeOut(1000, "linear", null) }), 2000);
```

This removes the bounding box, but I can't reopen it.

```
setTimeout((function () { $(thisDialog).parent().fadeOut(1000, "linear", null) }), 2000);
```

This allows me to reopen it, but it doesn't fade.  I would like the fade effect.

```
setTimeout((function () { $(thisDialog).dialog("close"); }), 2000);
```

Comment: Post a complete code example please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked.  Not sure why.

```
   setTimeout((function () {
                $(thisDialog).parent().fadeOut(1000, "linear", null);
                $(thisDialog).dialog("close");

            }), 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Use build-in option `hide` (and `show`):

```
$('#dialog').dialog({
    hide:{
        duration: 1000,
        easing: 'linear',
        effect: 'fade',
    },
});
```

[fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/cgsrs657/)